# How to use a variable in multiple DataGrip queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datagrip

Given I have a bunch of queries
E.g.

```
delete from permissions where user_id = 9845 and project_id =2;
delete from users_projects where user_id = 9845 and project_id =2;
delete from users where id = 9845 and project_id =2;
```

How can I avoid having to update the user_id in each query each time I run these?

Ideally, something like

```
var userId = 9845

delete from permissions where user_id = userId and project_id =2;
delete from users_projects where user_id = userId and project_id =2;
delete from users where id = userId and project_id =2;
```

I tried using `?` and `:userId`
E.g.

```
delete from permissions where user_id = :userId and project_id =2;
delete from users_projects where user_id = :userId and project_id =2;
delete from users where id = :userId and project_id =2;
```

This prompts me to enter a User Id via a dialog, which is fine, except I have to enter ir for each row.

I want to be able to update one place / enter the value once.

Is this possible with DataGrip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `${variable_name}` syntax to enter a value only once for queries:

```sql
delete from permissions where user_id = ${userId} and project_id =2;
delete from users_projects where user_id = ${userId} and project_id =2;
delete from users where id = ${userId} and project_id =2;
```